# Are there any missile systems as of 2019 capable of shooting down aircraft in excess of mach 6?

Tags: missiles

Are there any missile systems, ground based, or air to air, as of 2019 that are capable of shooting down aircraft in excess of mach 6, such as the X-15?

For simplicity I'm ignoring the fact that the X-15 may be considered a spacecraft or "space plane".

Comment: Asking for a friend, of course.

Comment: @DavidRicherby a friend in the Iranian ministry of defense procurement office?

Comment: @jwenting Not necessarily. It could be a friend who owns a very fast plane.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Russian S-400 SAM System is claimed to be capable of speeds in excess of Mach 12 and ranges of 400 km (250 miles).  It can, in theory successfully engage and defeat hypersonic targets, albeit with a much smaller lethal envelope than against conventional aircraft or missiles